# Создать новый столбец с длинами строк в другом столбце (для NaN длина -> 0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

При попытке создать новый столбец, который состоит из количества символов другого поста, сталкиваюсь с ошибкой:

```
p = 1
for p in range(133380):
    if df['Текст':p] == 'NaN':
        df['Кол-во символов':p] = 0
        p = p + 1
    else:
        df['Кол-во символов':p] = len(df['Текст':p])
        p = p + 1
```

Comment: Что за ошибка ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по коду вы пытаетесь создать новый столбец, содержащий длину строки в столбце `Текст`. Для этого не нужен цикл.

Пример DF:

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]:
         Текст
0          123
1          NaN
2  aaaaaaaaaaa
3          ccc
4          NaN
5           bb
6
7         dddd
```

Решение:

```
In [18]: df['Кол-во символов'] = df['Текст'].fillna('').str.len()
```

Результат:

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]:
         Текст  Кол-во символов
0          123                3
1          NaN                0
2  aaaaaaaaaaa               11
3          ccc                3
4          NaN                0
5           bb                2
6                             0
7         dddd                4
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!